# Dual boot Windows 10 Ubuntu14.04 problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I'm sorry if this question has been asked before, but I couldn't find a solution that worked for me.

I recently got a new laptop with Windows 8.1. I added an SSD and installed Windows 8.1 on that drive. Now I upgraded to Windows 10 and decided I wanted a dual boot with Ubuntu. The installation of Ubuntu went fine, but now there are some problems with booting.

When I start my laptop, Windows boots automatically. I can access Ubuntu by pressing F12 while booting, but this is not ideal. I would like to load GRUB when booting, but GRUB only shows up when choosing ubuntu from the F12 menu.

I tried messing around a bit with EasyBCD, but it didn't help. 
I already tried Boot Repair. Here is the url: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11965416/

I don't know enough about this stuff to fix this, but I would like to know what is going on, so I would very much appreciate if someone could tell me what the problem is (although I would also be happy if it just started working correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your boot priority so grub takes president over the Windows bootloader. In your UEFI go to Boot and look for something similar to `Boot Option Priorities` and set Boot Option #1 to `ubuntu (P#: drive name)`. This should set grub as your default boot device. It is also worth noting that devices such as `ubuntu (size)` and `Windows Boot Manager (P# drive name)` will both default to the Windows bootloader whereas `ubuntu (P#: drive name)` defaults to grub.

See screen capture for reference:

[image: UEFI BIOS]

Comment: He has 2 UEFI partitions, so I wouldn't know where to start (look again at the boot-repair info)

Comment: I already looked at that, without result, but when checking again, I noticed that there was no grub option available. I added the grubx64.efi file to the secure boot files and after a reboot it showed up in the list. After setting it as the first boot device it worked :) Thanks!