# Mounting WIN 10 partition problem

Tags: mount, windows-10

I apologize if this is a duplicate - I searched the forums as well other sites for answers but without success...

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a Win 10 VAIO laptop, but I can't access the main partition, with the following error message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda5 at /media/yoni/CC1C14161C13FA62: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda5" "/media/yoni/CC1C14161C13FA62"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I already did the following:

1. Disabled both fast boot and secure boot and tried shutting down and restarting multiple times.
2. Tried shutting down using `run` with `shutdown /s /f /t 0`.
3. In cmd tried `powercfg /h off` [as suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457224/failed-to-access-windows-8-1-ntfs-partition-from-ubuntu-13-10-even-after-disabl) but ran into an error, I'm not sure why but maybe it only works on Win 8.
4. Ran `ntfsfix /dev/sda5` in terminal, but got the following error:

   ```
   Mounting volume... Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
   FAILED
   Attempting to correct errors...
   Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
   Reading $MFT... OK
   Reading $MFTMirr... OK
   Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
   Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
   Setting required flags on partition... OK
   Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
   Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
   Remount failed: Operation not permitted
   ```

I also have another common problem that might be related:
Windows boot loader overrides Ubuntu boot loader. I'm currently working around it by typing

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

in cmd before shutting down from windows whenever I want to load Ubuntu. I'll also try [this suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654554/dual-boot-windows-10-ubuntu14-04-problem), but for the moment I'm only mentioning this in case it can somehow be related.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but both this link and the link within it are pages I already checked out, and either tried the methods or they weren't helpful (e.g. opening in read-only state), except deleting the hiberfile, which I'm not sure I want to risk damaging stuff.

Comment: I'm marking this as a duplicate- the thing that finally made it work was powercfg /h off, which for some reason didn't work at first, but later on did work and sealed the deal. Thanks!